# Using GPUs with Statevector Simulator in Qiskit 1.0

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I'm trying to use the `AerStatevector` method with GPUs. I know that GPUs on my server are correctly configured, and indeed, if I use `AerSimulator` I'm able to use them with no problem.
Now, by using the following code: `AerStatevector(qc, device='GPU')` where `qc` is a given quantum circuit, I'm getting the following error:

```
 RuntimeError: This program was not compiled for SM 61  
: cudaErrorInvalidDevice: invalid device ordinal
```

On the other hand, If I use just  `AerStatevector(qc)`, it works correctly.
Any hints?
More generally, I'm moving to qiskit 1.0, and I would like to perform statevector simulations by using GPUs.

Where can I look for some tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/main/docs/tutorials/1_aersimulator.ipynb) tutorial out. There's a mention of using GPU with AerSimulator.